# Android Studio Emulator Panic Could not Find

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, panic

I'm trying to run the emulator for Android Studio and am getting this error.

PANIC: Could not find Nexus_S_Main_activity_API_21.ini file in $ANDROID_AVD_HOME nor in $HOME/.android/avd

How can I fix this? Keep in mind that I am a complete beginner so please try to explain each step clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you made the same mistake like me running Android studio as sudo. So actually in my case Studio created ini files in /root/.android/avd instead of /home//.android/avd . I just copied the files of my emulator from root to my home folder and it worked like a charm ! But I also verified it by noticing the ini file path in properties of the avd which you can also see if you select details in your AVD manager. I hope it helps and if it does then do accept it as answer :)